# Shell script input doesn't work for npm init

Tags: bash, shell, npm

I'm learning to write shell scripts in terminal. I'm trying to automate the npm init process, just for the sake of an exercise. So I read in all the parameters from terminal, then try to automatically execute an `npm init` with them. However, the process always aborts when `npm init` asks for the entry point. Anywhere else just leaving a blank line to simulate an enter key press, or using the variable works fine. Why does it quit at that point?

```
read -p "Project name: " name;
read -p "Version: " version;
read -p "Project description: " description;
read -p "Entry point: " entryPoint;
read -p "Test command: " testCommand;
read -p "Git repository: " gitRepo;
read -p "Keywords: " keywords;
read -p "Author: " author;
read -p "License: " license;
read -p "Is this okay?: " isOkay;

npm init <<!
$name
$version
$description
$entryPoint
$testCommand
$gitRepo
$author
$license
$isOkay
!
```

Terminal input and results when running script:

```
Project name: name
Version: 1.0.0
Project description: description
Entry point: app.js
Test command: 
Git repository: 
Keywords: 
Author: Author
License: ISC
Is this okay?: yes
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (node) name
version: (1.0.0) 1.0.0
description: description
entry point: (index.js)
```

And that's it. It quits at entry point every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this does not work, but a program can read user input without directly using stdin. It is possible that npm falls into this category.

For such cases the solution for passing text to prompt is to use the `expect` command.

```
read -p "Project name: " name;
read -p "Version: " version;
read -p "Project description: " description;
read -p "Entry point: " entryPoint;
read -p "Test command: " testCommand;
read -p "Git repository: " gitRepo;
read -p "Keywords: " keywords;
read -p "Author: " author;
read -p "License: " license;
read -p "Is this okay?: " isOkay;


/usr/bin/expect <<!

spawn npm init
expect "package name:"
send "$name\n" 
expect "version:"
send "$version\n" 
expect "description:"
send "$description\n" 
expect "entry point:"
send "$entryPoint\n" 
expect "test command:"
send "$testCommand\n" 
expect "git repository"
send "$gitRepo\n" 
expect "keywords:"
send "$keywords\n" 
expect "author:"
send "$author\n" 
expect "license:"
send "$license\n" 
expect "Is this ok?"
send "$isOkay\n"
expect eof
!
echo "DONE!"
```

Comment: Interesting. This works - thanks. There is a delay of about 10 seconds right after `spawn npm init`. Any idea why?

Comment: @cweber105, I changed the expect from `expect "Is this ok?"` to `expect "Is this OK? (yes)"` and it resolved the problem on my end. Machine: MacOS.

Comment: Expect func looks for a pattern as input. `expect "Is this O*" ` seemed to work!

Comment: Because expect was not matching the input exactly the delay was 10 seconds until the expect function terminated itself. 