# Answer a few prompts for installing npm modules

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I'd like to install and register some information at once.

What I want is

```
npm install -g <some package>
# installing..

npm register some-information # this line make three prompts I have to answer like id, password and email.
```

How do I respond prompts using shell scripts?

Comment: For Linux use expect command. This answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217469/6766425

Comment: @ImanRb Thank you for helping me. It works well but I needed to install expect first.